# PHP ob_start() and ob_start('ob_gzhandler')

Tags: php, buffer, content-encoding

What is the difference between using `ob_start()` and `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` ?
How does it affect the page speed ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This doesn't affect page speed in the sense you'd might think.

the [ob_gzhandler](http://php.net/ob_gzhandler) is a callback function which takes the contents from your output buffer and compresses the data before outputting it.

This reduces the **size** of the content being sent to the browser which might speed up the content transfer to the client. But it doesn't speed up your application/website.

Comment: If a page uses ob_start('ob_gzhandler') which speeds up the content transfer to the client, I think this buffering may speed up that page rendering as well.

Comment: Those two things is not related to eachother. Page rendering depends on the clients hardware. It doesn't matter if I can have the content in 1 second if rendering the content takes 3 seconds. You still have to fetch the content before you can render anything.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to force gzip for some admin pages (full of complicated HTML tables) that weren't being automatically compressed for some clients so I added this method. I'm not sure I would force it for every page, but at least the admin pages its fine.

```
function force_gzip()
{
    // Ensures only forced if the Accept-Encoding header contains "gzip"
    if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
    {
        header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    }
}
```

950Kb of HTML was compressed down around 80KB resulting in a 5-10x speed increasing loading the page.